# Display a box of increasing number with order

Tags: java, algorithm

**CODE**

```
        int rows=3, columns=3, i, j;
        for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
        {
            for(j = 1; j <= columns; j++)
            {
                if(i == 1 || i == rows || j == 1 || j == columns)
                {
                    System.out.print(count); 
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" "); 
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n"); 

        }
```

The following piece of code outputs the following:

**OUTPUT**

```
123
4 5
678
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
123
8 4
765
```

Basically creating a board game which has to start from one position and end at the same position completing a full circle., in this case a square.

Any Ideas ??

Comment: Will it always be a `3x3` matrix?

Comment: @NicholasK no... it can increase(keeping  a cap at 8)...but it will always be a square

Comment: Say, if its a `6x6` matrix, you will face numbers greater than 10. How will your square be aligned as each number will take up 2 positions?

Comment: @NicholasK I get where you are going at...But this is just a representation/position of the actual value which i will get an array...alignment is not an issue...Gave the above as an example of how I want my tiles to be represented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experiments, this could work:

```
public static void printBox(int rows, int columns) {

    int sumOfColumns = 2 * columns + rows - 1;
    int sumOfRow = 2 * columns + 2 * rows - 2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                System.out.printf(String.format("%3d", j));
            } else if (j == 1) {
                System.out.printf(String.format("%3d", sumOfRow - (i + j - 1)));
            } else if (j == columns) {
                System.out.printf(String.format("%3d", i + j - 1));
            } else if (i == rows) {
                System.out.printf(String.format("%3d", sumOfColumns - j));
            } else {
                System.out.print("   ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printBox(3, 3);
    printBox(4, 4);
    printBox(3, 4);
}
```

Result:

```
  1  2  3
  8     4
  7  6  5

  1  2  3  4
 12        5
 11        6
 10  9  8  7

  1  2  3  4
 10        5
  9  8  7  6
```

Comment: Had to make some slight changes ...But works perfectly thanks :)

Comment: @rohitthomas that changes are for alignment

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a 2 dimensional array:

```
gameBoard[3][3];
```

then populate that board with the desired values. After the gameboard is complete, you can write another function to print the board.

Comment: But that will result in changing the layout completely, not to mention the architecture of how my current logic works ... I was wonder if its possible to do it with a 1-D array ??